# failed to open sqlite database with persian character in the path

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, persian, non-english

I am using a SQLite database for my program. Everything works fine when I am using English characters in the database path . but when I want to open my SQLite database with Persian characters in its path it fails to open . I searched the internet and found two answers for other languages but it did not worked for Persian. 
the two option:

First option:

```
         var dbPath2 =
Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.Path,
"test.db");
            string utf8String = String.Empty;
            // Get UTF16 bytes and convert UTF16 bytes to UTF8 bytes
            byte[] utf16Bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(dbPath2);
            byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode,
Encoding.UTF8, utf16Bytes);
            // Fill UTF8 bytes inside UTF8 string
            for (int i = 0; i < utf8Bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                // Because char always saves 2 bytes, fill char with 0
                byte[] utf8Container = new byte[2] { utf8Bytes[i], 0 };
                utf8String += BitConverter.ToChar(utf8Container, 0);
            }
            string dbPath = utf8String;
            var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath)
```

---

Second option (In Sqlite.cs comes when you add the reference)

```
        public SQLiteConnection(string databasePath, bool
storeDateTimeAsTicks = false)
        {
            DatabasePath = databasePath;
            Sqlite3DatabaseHandle handle;
            var r = SQLite3.Open16(DatabasePath, out handle);
            Handle = handle;
            if (r != SQLite3.Result.OK)
            {
                throw SQLiteException.New(r, String.Format("Could not
open database file: {0} ({1})", DatabasePath, r));
            }
            _open = true;
            StoreDateTimeAsTicks = storeDateTimeAsTicks;
            BusyTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1);
        }
```

thanks

Comment: What error message do you get when it fails to open? Can you give an example of a path that produces this error message?

Comment: It may be imposed by OS not SQlite. Why you just don't use English characters? Many other applications have such problems with Persian characters.

Comment: The Error is Could not open database file: D:\programming\laitner\92_7_29\WpfLaitner3\WpfLaitner3\bin\Debug\عباس\database3.sql (14)

Comment: please help me. no one Knows what should I do??????????????????????????????????????